# How to send reply for user submitted form in wordpress using gravity forms plugins

Tags: wordpress, add-on, gravity-forms-plugin

In Wordpress Gravity form,
How to send reply for user submitted enquires,(Not Default notification Email)
I need to send Particular reply for that enquires.
(or)
Is there is any plugin or add ons to send reply for any form.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Gravity Forms allows you to configure multiple notifications that can be sent conditionally. Just click the "Add New" button on the Notifications page for your form and configure the conditional logic at the bottom to only send when the required conditions are met.